# variable in bash script does not take the right value as expected

Tags: bash, shell, automation, openstack

Why does the status variable not take the value of the cat command as written, knowing that the cat command before the right content? I have been looking for some hours now : check the lines with (*)

```
if [ ! -f "node.txt" ]; then
     echo " File computes_to_delete not found"
     exit 1;
fi

while read -r compute_to_delete; do
    compute_to_delete=${compute_to_delete}
    compute_sh=${compute_to_delete}.sh
    { cat << EOF;} > "$compute_sh"
#!/bin/bash
echo "compute to be deleted"
echo  $compute_to_delete
openstack compute service list
openstack compute service set $compute_to_delete nova-compute --enable
openstack compute service list --long -c Binary -c Host -c Status -f json | jq -r '.[] | select(.Host == "$compute_to_delete" ) | .Status' > status.txt
(*) cat status.txt
(*) STATUS=$(< status.txt)
echo "$STATUS"

if [ "$STATUS" == "enabled" ]; then


fi

openstack server list --host $compute_to_delete --all-projects
EOF

done < computes_hosts.txt
```

---

As suggested in the comments, I've added backslashes before the concerned variable and now its working fine

```
if [ ! -f "node.txt" ]; then
     echo " File computes_to_delete not found"
     exit 1;
fi

while read -r compute_to_delete; do
    compute_to_delete=${compute_to_delete}
    compute_sh=${compute_to_delete}.sh
    { cat << EOF;} > "$compute_sh"

#!/bin/bash
echo "compute to be deleted"
echo  $compute_to_delete
openstack compute service list
openstack compute service set $compute_to_delete nova-compute --enable
openstack compute service list --long -c Binary -c Host -c Status -f json | jq -r '.[] | select(.Host == "$compute_to_delete" ) | .Status' > status.txt
 cat status.txt
 STATUS=\$(< status.txt)
echo "\$STATUS"

if [ "\$STATUS" == "enabled" ]; then


fi

openstack server list --host $compute_to_delete --all-projects
EOF

done < computes_hosts.txt
```

Comment: use `<< 'EOF'` so that variables in the here-doc won't be expanded.

Comment: @Barmar I have just tried but no it still not getting right value, and also after adding the ' ' even the cat is no more showing the content

Comment: It looks like you have a problem. You want `$compute_to_delete` to be expanded, but you don't want `$STATUS` to be expanded. So go back to the original `<<`, but put backslash before the `$` that should not be expanded.

Comment: E.g. `STATUS=\$(< status.txt)` and `echo "\$STATUS"`

Comment: Both methods are explained in the linked question.

Comment: If you have modified the code, please update your question and **add** (don't replace!)  the new code which, despite its corrections, does not work. Also don't put weird `(*)` into your code. If you want to provide inline explanation, do it as a comment (`#....`).